# How to create JSON formatted string from multiple lists in python?

Tags: python, json

I have 3 lists,

```
city_id = [1,2,3]
city_name = ['a','b','c']
city_capital = ['x','y','z']
```

How to combine the above three lists into a json in the below format without iterating over by myself. Is there any library function available in python to get the job done?

```
[
    {
        'city_id': 1,
        'city_name': 'a',
        'city_capital': 'x'
    },
    {
        'city_id': 2,
        'city_name': 'b',
        'city_capital': 'y'
    },
    {
        'city_id': 3,
        'city_name': 'c',
        'city_capital': 'z'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list with data in that form:

```
[ { 'city_id': x, 'city_name': y, 'city_capital': z } 
  for x, y, z in zip(city_id, city_name, city_capital) ]
```

If you want to output the data in **exactly** that form, then you can use the suggestion by @AndyKubiak in the comments:

```
import json
d = [ { 'city_id': x, 'city_name': y, 'city_capital': z } 
      for x, y, z in zip(city_id, city_name, city_capital) ]
pretty_json = json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: I'd just add a call to `import json`, then wrap that beautiful comprehension of yours with `pretty_json = json.dumps(beautiful_comprehension, sort_keys=True, indent=4)` from the "Pretty printing" example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).